# Possibilities for intersections of 2 non-parallel planes in 4 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, intersection-theory

I'm trying to solve question 9 of page B24 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-024-multivariable-calculus-with-theory-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT18_024s11_ChB1notes.pdf).

My attempt:

I claim that the possibilites are one of the following

- An empty set.
- A point.
- A line.

For the first case, consider the following example
$$x=0,y=0 \text{ and } x=1,z=0 .$$
For the second case, consider
$$x=0,y=0 \text{ and } z=0,w=0 $$
For the last case, consider
$$x=0,y=0 \text{ and } y=0,z=0 $$

Since the planes are not parallel, they can't coincide, so an intersection of dimension two is impossible. Obviously intersections of higher dimensions are also impossible. Am I correct here? On a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768368/intersection-of-2d-planes-in-4d-space) it is said that an empty intersection is impossible in the non-parallel case, yet I think it is possible.

Thank you!

Comment: @amd What's wrong with my first example?

Comment: Right. Sorry.  Forgot that we’re in $\mathbb R^4$, so just as one can have skew lines in $\mathbb R^3$, there’s enough room for “skew planes.” By definition, for planes to be called “parallel” in $\mathbb R^4$, they must lie in the same 3-dimensional subspace. That answer that you’re citing is incorrect.

Comment: @amd However, if we use the definition of parallelism on page [A32](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-024-multivariable-calculus-with-theory-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT18_024s11_ChAnotes.pdf), am I correct?

Comment: Beats me. I’m not going to go digging through off-site scanned documents to answer this. That applies to your original question, BTW: you’re much more likely to draw responses if your questions are self-contained.